# EJB JTA/JPA CMT transaction rollback affects child transactions

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I'm having a problem with transaction rollback in which a sub-transaction annotated with REQUIRES_NEW is being rolled back because the parent transaction was rolled back. I am puzzled because I had thought that JTA/JPA treated these transactions independently so that rollback on one did not affect the other.  I'm using Java 1.6.0_24, EJB 3.1, GlassFish 3.0.1, JPA 2, MS SQL Server (non-XA) 2008, CMT.

The example below shows the essence: A Process EJB in its own TN invokes the auditor at its start, performs DB actions but determines failure, sets rollback, and then invokes auditor upon completion. An Auditor EJB invokes JPA to create an audit record in a separate transaction (REQUIRES_NEW) and this works fine when the transaction is successful.  The code shows a generic auditing structure with all unnecessary code omitted--the generics appear to be part of the problem.

```
public interface ErrorDescriptor {  
    public String getName ();  
}  

public interface GenericAuditor<T extends ErrorDescriptor> {
    public void log(T errorType);
}

public abstract class AbstractGenericAuditorImpl<T extends ErrorDescriptor>
    implements GenericAuditor<T> {
}

public enum AuditType implements ErrorDescriptor {
   BEGIN, FAILED;
    public String getName() { return name(); }
}

public interface Auditor extends GenericAuditor<AuditType> {
    // The absence of the following 2 lines causes the problem
    @Override
    public void log(AuditType errorType);
}

@Stateless
public class AuditorImpl
    extends AbstractGenericAuditorImpl<AuditType>
    implements Auditor {
    @PersistenceContext ("EntityPersistenceManagement")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void log (AuditType e) {
        ErrorEvent errorEvent = new ErrorEvent (); // entity
        errorEvent.setName (e.getName());
        entityManager.persist (errorEvent);
   }
}

@Stateless
public class ProcessImpl implements Process {
    @Resource private EJBContext ejbContext;
    @EJB private Auditor auditor;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void method1() {
    auditor.log(AuditType.BEGIN);

    // Perform series of actions including database ops
    // Takes up to 1 minute
    // Somethings happen that detects failure
    ejbContext.setRollbackOnly ();

    auditor.log(AuditType.FAILED);
}
}
```

The issue is that when parent.method1() is invoked it proceeds quietly until it determines failure and sets rollback.  At that point the 2nd audit call throws Client's Transaction Aborted as if it were part of the current transaction rather than in a separate transaction. Moreover, the first audit call puts no data in the database--even when successful it does not commit until the parent commits (is that normal?) This should be non-XA in separate transactions.

I've read many articles that claim the transactions are independent, but  [this one](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions) suggests that nested transactions do not commit until the parent commits and that if the parent rollsback, the children rollback also.  I don't see how I could commit partial or status work if that were true because nothing would commit until the top most transaction committed.

JPA Config--I originally used a single data source but later switched to two but I observed no differences.

```
<persistence-unit name="EntityPersistenceManagement" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>jdbc/app1</jta-data-source>
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving.internal" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving.changetracking" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving.lazy" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving.internal" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving.eager" value="false"/>

    <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared" value = "false"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
</properties>

<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<class>org.foo.entities.AppRecord</class>
<class>org.foo.entities.ErrorEvent</class>
```

Can anyone say if that's how rollback is supposed to work?  Perhaps this is different under XA?

I have uploaded this [annotated transaction log](http://www.iviz.com/tightwire/jpa-1.txt) look for ** entries for control points within the code.

ADDED: This [**second log**](http://www.iviz.com/tightwire/jpa-3.txt) has EclipseLink level at FINEST.

EDIT: I have revised the code to show exactly what causes the problem and returned to only one persistence manager.

Comment: The snippet you posted is correct and should work exactly as you described. Could you give us the JPA configuration (to check you are specifying the correct JTA configuration)

Comment: That should work as you describe -- I used the same technique to audit error and it worked. Try to turn on the tx manager logs in GF admin console and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply--are you confirming that nested transactions are not independent (parent rollback causes child rollback)? I don't see how this reconciles with 13.6.2.4 of the EJB 3.1 spec. I keep reading that JTA/JPA do not support nested transactions (flat transactions only) but yet there they are.

Comment: The fact that JTA/JPA don't support nested transactions has nothing to do with your problem and solution. When you invoke an EJB method with REQUIRES_NEW tx attribute from a running EJB transaction, a brand new transaction has to be created which is completely independent from the "original" transaction. They won't be nested.

Comment: @Csaba That's great and I would prefer for EJB to work without nested transactions, but can you help me understand why so-called completely independent transactions are rolled back when the parent transaction rolls back?

Comment: The actual code (part of a very large system that I cannot post) is more complex than what I have shown so I'm attempting to assemble an SSCCE to demonstrate the problem.  The simplified code of the original post does work correctly (does not rollback children), so there is some issue in how it is structured in my application.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the closest simplification possible and can reliably cause / fix the problem.  When the log declaration in the Auditor interface is not present a new transaction is not created and committed child transactions are rolled back. But when the declaration is present, the code works correctly, REQUIRES_NEW is honored by creating new transactions and children are not rolled back. The declaration should be unnecessary because it is fully implied by the concrete generic parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is a bug with GlassFish https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-8319, documented as resolved in v 3.1.

Comment: +1 For find the bug report! I always new generics were evil ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have quite similar issue(with kind of case). In inner transaction I had an update in db, but when parent transaction was finishing, I had an OptimisticLockException, telling the record had already been updated.

Knowing about UnitOfWorks from EclipeLink doc, I think(at least it works=) have solved the issue. The problem was that parent UnitOfWork did not know about changes I'd made in RequiresNew transaction. And in the successfull end of parent transaction 'Parent' UnitOfWork contained change for UPDATE.
So I have added **em.refresh()** right after RequiresNew call. Results of inner transaction - applied. Parent transaction - successfully finishing.

**Matt**, you wrote:

> So if I am getting nested transactions, it's not clear how to create isolated, definate commits for auditing that will not rollback when the parent rollsback.

Maybe em.refresh() would solve the issue? Maybe your parent UnitOfWork rollback db to the start state.

Matt, thanks for bunch of references.

Answer (score 0):

They should be independent.  It could be a bug somewhere, can you please include the log of the failed transaction on finest.

Comment: Added link to main question--log is pretty big.

Comment: I meant the EclipseLink log on finest, your log does not include any EclipseLink logging

Comment: The log only shows one "Created new JavaEETransactionImpl" so it does not look like Glassfish is creating two transactions.  Ensure you have compiled/deployed your code correctly.

Comment: Undeploying app, restarting GlassFish (clearing OSGI, etc) are necessary testing techniques, but I've tried many different tests without success.  My actual auditor class inherits from abstract utility (EAO) superclasses that work fine in other applications so I'm suspecting there is some subtle difference in the declaration that is affecting the transactions. The REQUIRES_NEW is being ignored and everything is happening in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that your process is running within a global transaction (distributed), therefore, if one transaction fails the rest of them will not commit. (like the behavior that you are describing)

You wrote:

> "JPA Config--I originally used a single data source **but later switched**
>   to two but I observed no differences."

For me this is the problem: when you add a new resource the Transaction Manager automatically assumes that now the transactions need to be distributed.

> "... note that 2-Phase-Commit does not add value for single resources-
>   only for transactions spanning multiple resources. An efficient
>   transaction manager will fall back to simple 1-Phase-Commit if
>   touching only a single resource, although this is merely suggested
>   rather than required by the J2EE specification"

From book [Expert One on One J2EE Development without EJB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764558315) p. 233

I was reading you last log, to me it is clear that the **transaction is global**, therefore, you should try to change this behavior.

I don't know how your framework actually works, but I was curious about a class that appear in the log:

`com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate`

I saw that it implements the `com.sun.enterprise.transaction.spi.JavaEETransactionManagerDelegate` interface.

According to [the source code's comments](http://grepcode.com/file/maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/org.glassfish.main.transaction/jta/4.0-b63/com/sun/enterprise/transaction/JavaEETransactionManagerSimplifiedDelegate.java#JavaEETransactionManagerSimplifiedDelegate):

Implementation of JavaEETransactionManagerDelegate that supports XA transactions with JTS.

`public class JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate`

Implementation of JavaEETransactionManagerDelegate that supports only local transactions with a single non-XA resource.

`public class JavaEETransactionManagerSimplifiedDelegate`

I don't know how to configure you framework, but it seems to be that you need to tell him that other implementation (JavaEETransactionManagerSimplifiedDelegate) must be used for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I originally observed this problem under a single non-XA data source as well as under MySQL, but I will re-test that condition to confirm.

Comment: Retest has same behavior and transaction log shows all transaction have the same id.

Comment: I tried to make a comment buy it was too long, so I modified the answer

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct, but I have already marked the transaction and its parent as REQUIRES_NEW. I'm using straight EJB 3.1 in GlassFish 3.0.1 so I don't do anything special configure the transaction manager. I've added more info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bunch of references that together imply that although EJB does not supported nested transactions, EclipseLink (GlassFish) does, which may at least explain the problem.

[**EJB 3.1 Spec**](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) section 13.1.2 clearly states transactions are flat and there are no nested transactions. Section 15.6.1.2 says compliant containers must not use nested transactions. Section 13.6.2.4 says REQUIRES_NEW will suspend the current transaction and resume after the 2nd transaction commits.

[**JPA/JTA WikiBooks**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions#Nested_Transactions) in the "Nested Transactions" states again they are not supported and then gives a comprehensive definition of them that matches the behavior I am seeing.

[**The JTA 1.0.1 Spec**](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7286-jta-1.0.1-spec-oth-JSpec/) section 3.1 says that nested transactions are not *required* which may imply they are possible.

But this [**EclipseLink wiki entry**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Transactions_%28ELUG%29#Nested_and_Parallel_Units_of_Work) shows that they DO support nested "units of work" in which nested commits are not independent but deferred until the parent commit.  This actually matches the behavior I am seeing.

So if I am getting nested transactions, it's not clear how to create isolated, definate commits for auditing that will not rollback when the parent rollsback.